# windows.open() works once then fails

Tags: javascript, asp.net, charts

The following code opens a window correctly to display a chart of a selected row of data, but when used on a second selection it fails.

```
OnClientClick="window.open        
('NewChart.aspx','zxyzxy','top=10,left=20,height=600,width=800'); return false"
```

Fiddler shows the following 404 description for the failure:
  [image]

The problem appears to be that it is looking for ChartImg.axd in the root of my website, but there is no file of that name, nor any bearing the name 'zxyzxy' that I gave to the chart.

The chartImageHandler in webconfig appears to be the problem because it bears reference to ChartImg.axd:

```
<add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode"  
 verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" .....
```

This suggests that it may simply be a directory reference issue but as I don't find a file of that name to redirect, it may be more complicated.

I have been fighting this problem for more than a month and no solution that I have found works. PLEASE can someone suggest how to get around the problem. Window.Close('zxyzxy') simply closes the webpage, not the chart window!

Comment: Almost gave up on understanding the problem. You have 80% of space dedicated to fiddler issue and not your own question...

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the reference to the cahrt window object, when you open it. Then you can close.

```
var x = window.open("test.html","test");

x.close()
```